Объясните общие понимания работы программы с источниками данных
Пишу систему, у которой в начале входа нужно выбирать БД(и настроить ее) или файловое хранение(и тоже настроить по типу места базирования).
По выбранному источнику хранения программа должны работать от начала и до конца своей работы.
Исходя из этого возникли вопросы как заложить архитектуру использования программой - источника данных.
То есть:

Как программа должна хранить состояние выбранного источника данных, чтобы можно им пользоваться из любой части программы.
Как взаимодействовать с выбранным источником.
Как взаимодействовать с выбранным источником если нужны разные действия, запросы, выборки, запись и т.д.
Какие использовать паттерны для организации работы программы с источником данных
и то что еще может быть при работе с источниками данных

Разъясните пожалуйста принципы работы программы при выборе разных источников данных или поделитесь статейками, темами, где можно про это прочитать.

Паттерн Репозиторий.

Смотрите, основная суть тут в определении общих методов и свойств этих двух источников данных. К примеру, база и файл, нам надо "добавить" туда данные (Add) и "получить" их (Get), также наверно будут "изменить", "сохранить", "загрузить", и так далее, это уже зависит от вашего проекта. Разобравшись с тем, что связывает их, надо теперь создать "контракт", некий интерфейс, который будет требовать от класса реализацию всех этих методов и свойств. В итоге, у нас будет что-то такое:
public interface IDataRepository
{
    void Add(string value);
    string Get(string key);
}

Ну а дальше просто реализуйте под каждый источник данных свой класс, ну к примеру, пусть будет что-то такое:
public class DBRepository(string login, string password) : IDataRepository
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, string> _data = new();

    public void Add(string value)
    {
        _data.Add(value, value);
    }

    public string Get(string key)
    {
        return _data.TryGetValue(key, out var value) ? value : string.Empty;
    }
}

public class FileRepository(string filePath) : IDataRepository
{
    public void Add(string value)
    {
        File.AppendAllText(filePath, $"{value}\n");
    }

    public string Get(string key)
    {
        return File.ReadAllText(filePath).Contains(key) ? key : string.Empty;
    }
}

На реализацию не смотрите, я тут написал ее так, от балды, но суть думаю уловили, каждый класс имеет свою конкретную реализацию под конкретный источник данных.
Теперь, имея такое разделение, вы можете создать свойство/поле с типом данного интерфейса и в реальном времени задавать нужное значение. Например:
public IDataRepository? DataRepository { get; set; }

public void ChangeRepository(string type)
{
    DataRepository = type switch
    {
        "DB" => new DBRepository("login", "password"),
        "File" => new FileRepository("data.txt"),
        _ => throw new Exception("Invalid repository type")
    };
}

Собственно вот основной подход.
Теперь что касается остальных ваших вопросов:

Как программа должна хранить состояние выбранного источника данных.
Зависит очень сильно от того, как вы проектируете проект изначально. К примеру:

У вас может быть свой UI под каждый источник данных, а это значит, что под каждый UI стоит сделать свою ViewModel в которой и хранить конкретный объект.

Или у вас могут задаваться эти данные за пределами приложения (например, в JSON), тогда уже вам нужна либо "фабрика" (если вы не можете хранить тип конкретного класса), или прям в файле устанавливаете тип и десериализуете его сразу в нужный репозиторий ({ "$type" : "FileRepository", "Path": "file.txt" }. Далее, получив конкретный тип, вы можете сделать его обертку как Singleton и обращаться к ней где вам надо. Аналогично вы можете сделать через IoC контейнеры (вроде вы их знаете), где вам просто достаточно зарегистрировать этот тип после получения.


Ну и так далее, вариантов тут действительно много. В вашем случае мне кажется лучше всего подойдет создание некого класса "обертки", который будет в себе хранить сам IDataRepository, а также иметь метод его изменения, что-то вроде этого:
public class DataRepositoryService
{
    public IDataRepository? Data { get; private set; }
    public void SetRepository(IDataRepository dataRepository)
    {
        Data = dataRepository;
    }
}

Опять, пишу очень упрощенно, чтоб вы понимали логику. И вот у вас уже класс, который руководит всем этим, вам достаточно его один раз создать и дальше передавать куда хотите, ну или сделать его синглтоном, добавив к примеру что-то такое:
private static readonly Lazy<DataRepositoryService> _instance = new(() => new DataRepositoryService());
public static DataRepositoryService Instance => _instance.Value;

private DataRepositoryService()
{
}

Взаимодействие тогда будет таким: DataRepositoryService.Instance.SetRepository(...);, а если этот класс будет в контейнере, то вам вовсе достаточно будет попросить в любом месте экземпляр данного класса. Собственно вот вам простое хранение.

Как взаимодействовать с выбранным источником.
Как и с любым другим классом, получите объект, вызовите нужные свойства/методы, получите нужный результат. Самое главное, через интерфейс. Ну а если у вашего класса есть дополнительная логика (чего не желательно), то приведите к конкретному типу (FileRepisitory)Data;.

Остальные вопросы вроде и так затронул в ответе.


Тут у вас может возникнуть еще вопрос про UI, как его правильно создавать... Ох, а тут все довольно спорно, ибо у каждого свой подход и предпочтения, но давайте сделаем что-то простое.

Делаем интерфейс, который обобщит наши ViewModel (вы вроде знаете про них, если нет, пишите, объясню). В нем требуем событие, которое оповестит главную VM об изменении источника данных:
public interface IDataViewModelBase
{
    event Action<IDataRepository>? Created;
}


Реализуем под каждого источника свою VM, в которой прописываем все нужные данные для получения:
public partial class FileDataViewModel : IDataViewModelBase
{
    public event Action<IDataRepository>? Created;

    public string FilePath { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [RelayCommand]
    private void Create()
    {
        Created?.Invoke(new FileRepository(FilePath));
    }
}

public partial class DBDataViewModel : IDataViewModelBase
{
    public event Action<IDataRepository>? Created;

    public string Login { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [RelayCommand]
    private void Create()
    {
        Created?.Invoke(new DBRepository(Login, Password));
    }
}

На [RelayCommand] внимание не обращайте, это генерация ICommand от библиотеки CommunityToolkit.Mvvm. Вы у себя сделайте свои команды (вроде вы про Reactive интересовались, вот можно вроде через него сделать). Но не суть... В коде как видите простые свойства и метод, который будет вызван по нажатию кнопки.

Далее пишем главную VM, в ней будем хранить список с названием всех репозиториев (обычно он получается динамически, в моем примере это просто string), свойство текущего выбранного типа, ну и метод, который будет вызван при изменении свойства, и метод, который уже будет вызываться по событию конкретной VM.
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public string[] Repositories => [ "File", "DB" ];

    [ObservableProperty]
    private IDataViewModelBase? _selectedViewModel;

    private string _selectedRepository = string.Empty;
    public string SelectedRepository
    {
        get => _selectedRepository;
        set
        {
            _selectedRepository = value;
            OnSelectionChanged(value);
        }
    }

    private void OnSelectionChanged(string value)
    {
        if (SelectedViewModel is not null)
        {
            SelectedViewModel.Created -= SelectedViewModelCreated;
        }


        SelectedViewModel = value switch
        {
            "File" => new FileDataViewModel(),
            "DB" => new DBDataViewModel(),
            _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
        };

        SelectedViewModel.Created += SelectedViewModelCreated;
    }

    private void SelectedViewModelCreated(IDataRepository repository)
    {
        DataRepositoryService.Instance.SetRepository(repository);
    }
}


Делаем UI. Подход тут как у страниц, где в ресурсах мы сопоставляем при помощи DataTemplate тип с нужным видом (обычно этот вид разносят по отдельным UserControl), а в самом XAML окна/страницы привязываем ContentPresenter к нужному свойству.
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DBDataViewModel}">
        <StackPanel >
            <Grid Margin="10">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Логин: " FontWeight="Medium" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Пароль: " FontWeight="Medium" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Login}" />
                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Password}" />
            </Grid>

            <Button Margin="0 5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Создать"  Style="{DynamicResource DefaultAccentButtonStyle}"  Command="{Binding CreateCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:FileDataViewModel}">
        <StackPanel >
            <Grid Margin="10">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Путь: " FontWeight="Medium" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding FilePath}" />
            </Grid>

            <Button Margin="0 5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="Создать"  Style="{DynamicResource DefaultAccentButtonStyle}"  Command="{Binding CreateCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Margin="5">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Repositories}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRepository}"/>
    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"/>
</StackPanel>

В итоге результат наш будет таким:

Как видите, простое изменение ComboBox меняет и вид, ну а там уже при заполнении данных и нажатию на кнопку, будет вызвано событие, а оно в свою очередь вызовет SelectedViewModelCreated метод в котором я прописал изменение репозитория в сервисе (синглтон), ну а у вас своя реализация.


В общем, я вроде показал все, что вам потребуется, дальше уже разбирайтесь и подстраивайте под свои нужды. Главное, не лепите все в одну кучу, как говориться, разделяйте и властвуйте)
Удачи в изучении C#!

Как говорится, одна голова - хорошо, а две - лучше.

Оуу большое спасибо

Центр документации по данным .NET
Центр документации Entity Framework
Работа с данными в Visual Studio
Работа с БД в C#
Паттерн Репозиторий - METANIT.COM
Ща как расскажу!
Для начала ответы на вопросы.

Не должна. Состояние источника данных (ИД) можно получить в любой момент от него самого, и дублировать его в приложении не нужно.
Для этого внутри приложения должен быть драйвер ИД - объект, через который происходит всё взаимодействие. В случае использования Entity Framework - это Context.
Через драйвер. Драйвер может быть даже поверх Entity Framework. В драйвере нужно с удобным интерфейсом реализовать действия с данными, востребованные в приложении.
Паттерн - это некий готовый алгоритм, "стандартное решение". Не всегда нужно реализовывать такое решение в полном объёме, от ненужных частей и функций стоит отказаться. Подходящий паттерн упомянул @AlexanderPetrov в своём комментарии.
Абзац после пятого вопроса. Драйвер должен позволять использовать различные источники данных. Поэтому доступ к данным нужно сделать двухступенчатым - под "пользовательским" драйвером должны быть драйверы для каждого типа ИД.

Советую разрабатывать приложение, начиная с самых простых функций работы с ИД, и постепенно добавлять необходимые более сложные функции. Так будет выстраиваться интерфейс драйвера.
P. S. Про файловай источники данных. Начните с простого, например, с формата CSV. Это будет аналог таблицы в БД. Здесь будет очень легко создать драйвер, подходящий для обоих типов ИД. Не делайте большие объёмы, чтобы можно было начать с (временного) хранения массива данных в памяти.
Потом можно перейти к фомату XML (или JSON), который позволяет хранить иерархические структуры данных, что будет аналогом нескольких связанных таблиц (реляционной) БД.
В общем, это роман с продолжением, которое я писать не очень хочу. Евгений ниже правильно прокомментировал, в основном. Читайте по первым двум ссылкам, там найдёте много полезного.

Возможно стоит немного раскрыть ответ, чем просто ссылок накидать.

Ну как такую обширную тему раскроешь на полях Stackoverflow? А по ссылкам много чего есть: и примеры, и руководства, и справочники. Опять же: "Паттерн Репозиторий. – Alexander Petrov".

да вполне раскрывается, что там раскрывать то. Человек про принцип же спрашивает, рассказать про паттерн, привести пример и все дела.

Поясню и тут свой минус: Изначально у вас были ссылки на документацию, по типу "ей, человек, ищи сам", там очень поверхностно относилось все к вопросу, и какая от них польза? Я считаю, это вредным для SO, да и ссылки имеют особенность "протухания", уверены что будут действовать через 5 лет? А 50? Я вот нет... Сейчас информации больше, да, но минус снимать не будут так, как считаю это тоже поверхностной информацией, которая вряд ли поможет разобраться новичку. Вот человек условно спрашивает как обобщить работу с файлом и с базой, я у вас вижу разговор только про базу, еще и грузите EF'ом.

И вот опять, к чему про "источники данных" честно, не понимаю... Вот автору надо что-то по типу interface IDataRepository { T Read(); void Write(T item); } и далее class DBRepository : IDataRepository { public T Read (){  return данные из БД } public Write(T item) { db.Table.Add(item); }} и class FileRepository { T Read() {  return данные из файла }  void Write(T item){ .. } }, простой репозиторий. Но нет, вы в вопросе затронули все и очень поверхностно то, что требуется. Ну нельзя так. Это как в магазин зайти за водой, а продавец расскажет про бизнес, какие замечательные дети, и т.д.
